# Parsing a char array to array with function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have below function:

```
void get_name(char *a)
{
    char format[10];

    sprintf(format, "%%%ds", SIZE-1);
    scanf(format, a);
}
```

and then I am calling it within another function like below:

```
CListNode *initialize_list(int n)
{

    CListNode *end, *new, *first;
    CListNode *head=NULL;
    int i;
    char new_name[10];

    first=(CListNode *) malloc(sizeof(CListNode));
    strcpy(first->name, get_name(new_name));
    first->next=head;
    head=first;


    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        end=(CListNode *) malloc(sizeof(CListNode));
        strcpy(end->name, get_name(new_name));
        first->next=end;
        end->next=NULL;
    }

    return end;

}
```

on which CListNode is

```
typedef struct node
{
    char name[10];
    struct node * next;
} CListNode;
```

But I am getting this error "**Passing 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'const char *'**" twice (1 for each strcpy).

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
strcpy(first->name, get_name(new_name));
```

you can do

```
get_name(new_name);
strcpy(first->name, new_name);
```

If you want to keep the `strcpy(end->name, get_name(new_name));` lines, change the function so it returns a pointer to the input:

```
char *get_name(char *a)
{
    char format[10];

    sprintf(format, "%%%ds", SIZE-1);
    scanf(format, a);
    return a;
}
```

The issue is `strcpy(a,b)` copies the string `b` into `a`, but your function returns `void` so strcpy is left empty-handed.

From the looks of it, you're trying to program in a functional style ala lisp. Be careful, your function `get_name` is **destructive**, so it will modify `newname`.

Answer (score 0):

`get_name` is declared to return void, so in the call to `strcpy(first->name, get_name(new_name));` you're trying to copy nothing (void) into first->name.